# Dataweave key value set from database to HashMap

Tags: mule, dataweave

My flow goes something like this:

I receive a payload with say the following:

['BobsFirstStatus', 'BobsSecondStatus', 'BobsEightStatus']

and I have a lookup table in my database like so:

```
ID_|_BobStatusName___|_InternalStatusName_____
1  | BobsFirstStatus | Internal_1stStatus
2  | BobsSecondStatus| Internal_2ndStatus
3  | BobsEighStatus  | Internal_3rdStatus
```

I want to read this data from the database, and load a HashMap to look like so:

```
{
  "BobsFirstStatus": "Internal_1stStatus",
  "BobsSecondStatus": "Internal_2ndStatus",
  "BobsEighStatus": "Internal_3rdStatus"
}
```

this way, I can in a data weave statement i can do a "flowVars.Lookup[payload.BobStatus]" to retrieve our internal mapping of the status.

anyone done this before? seems useful...

Comment: I found another way to do this with the MapData method within a dataweave statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solid plan, although I don't like doing it in a flow variable. You can simply make a lookup flow, and call it from your DWL [like so](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#expressions-that-call-external-flows). You'll likely want to use Cache scope to avoid doing it every time.

I have done it in a spring bean before too, and I'm happy with the final result.  This is only for lookup tables that I expect to change only when the application is released, or less often.

1. Create a bean of type Map. You can use the native Spring `<util:map`> for this. Configure the lookup keys and values using spring `<entry>` elements

   `<util:map id="statusTable">`

   `<entry key="BobsFirstStatus" value="Internal_1stStatus" />`

   `<entry key="BobsSecondStatus" value="Internal_2ndStatus" />`

   `<entry key="BobsEighStatus" value="Internal_3rdStatus" />`

   `</util:map>`
2. Refer to the bean using the MEL `app` context object

   `#[app.registry.statusTable[flowVars.status]]`

Comment: that is really interesting! I needed the lookup to be db driven (admin users will change mappings based upon integrations) I'll post my answer as well. thanks Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving my issue with a script component using groovy below is the groovy script I used (note, i put the payload in a variable named "payload_cache" before calling a database select component):

```
def lookup = [:]
for (item in payload) {
    lookup[item['external_code']] = item['internal_code']
}
flowVars.NewResults = new ArrayList()
def ContainingDTO = flowVars.payload_cache.ContainingDTO
if (ContainingDTO){
    def ExternalItemList = ContainingDTO.ExternalItemList
    if (ExternalItemList){
        for (item in ExternalItemList){
            try{
                flowVars.NewResults.add(lookup[item])
            }catch(Exception){
                flowVars.NewResults.add('UNKNOWN')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Database component in cache component followed by a script component]